# change the baud rate stty on MAC terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, serial-port, stty

I need to use USB serial cable with baud rate of 115200.
I tried to set the rate with stty command from MACbook terminal application as follows;

```
$stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial-A103BTIB 115200
```

and confirmed the settings as follows;

```
$stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial-A103BTIB -a

&speed 9600 baud; 0 rows; 0 columns;
lflags: -icanon -isig -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoke -echonl
    -echoctl -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho -pendin
    -nokerninfo -extproc
iflags: -istrip -icrnl -inlcr -igncr -ixon -ixoff -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
    -ignbrk -brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: -opost -onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

It looks baud rate is till 9600. Could somebody show me how to change this step by step ?

Comment: Read the **man** page.  For OSX you need to precede the desired baudrate *number* with the keyword `speed`.

Comment: typed stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial-A103BTIB speed 115200 but still 9600....

Comment: Did you read the **man** page?  I can only find the OSX 10.9 **man** pages online.  What version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I did.  I use OSX 10.10.  Do you change the baud speed with stty with OSX 10.9 ?  Any possibility that this is an authorization problem ?

Comment: I don't use OSX.  If you mean permissions, then maybe.

Comment: I usually do something like this:  `exec 3<> /dev/cu.usbserial-AL02BXNR` and then the `stty` command. I think the baud rate only sticks if the port is opened.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is a common problem of stty command in OSX and not solved.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3798003?tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

I was able to set the baudrate temporarily by running screen session

```
$ screen /dev/cu.usbserial-FTHHQD0C 115200
```

and opening another terminal to run my script.

Comment: This is also useful if you want to talk to the serial port using screen (and need the changed speed)

Answer (score 2):

Other option to set a rigid baud value is to:

1. Launch a connection with the usbserial port, redirecting the output by `cat` in separate terminal window (to keep the port open):

`cat -v /dev/tty.usbserial-A103BTIB`

2. Set the baud:

`stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial-A103BTIB 115200`

The baud value stays set.